# Gridview sorting and paging events are not firing in embedded .ascx controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that's inside a .ascx control that's dynamically embedded into another .ascx control, which is then called by a web form.  The gridview will initially bind, but when any paging/sorting/command events are then triggered, I can't get any breakpoints inside the events to kick off. Additionally, when I look at the code-behind in the now-blank page, I see the old data sitting there.

Any idea what on earth is going on here?  For edification, the .ascx page with the control is excerpted.

Parent .ascx control:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smIndex" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" />
```

Child .ascx control:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAddAdj" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvAddAdjVenList" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Size="9px" Font-Names="Verdana" PageSize="10" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false" DataKeyNames="ID" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" OnRowDataBound="gvAddAdjVenList_RowDataBound" Visible="true">
```

In the child.ascx code-behind:

```
gvAddAdjVenList.DataBind();
gvAddAdjVenList.Sorting += new GridViewSortEventHandler(gvAddAdjVenList_Sorting);
gvAddAdjVenList.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(gvAddAdjVenList_PageIndexChanging);
```

Thanks!

valkyrie

Answer (score 0):

If you are 'dynamically embedding' the child control into another control from C#, ensure that you are assigning an ID to the child control:

```
gvAddAdjVenList.DataBind();      
gvAddAdjVenList.Sorting += new GridViewSortEventHandler(gvAddAdjVenList_Sorting);      
gvAddAdjVenList.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(gvAddAdjVenList_PageIndexChanging); 

gvAddAdjVenList.ID = "gvAddAdjVenList"; // Make sure you do this
parentControl.Controls.Add(gvAddAdjVenList);
```

to ensure that its events can be wired up correctly.

This was previously discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034644/itemcommand-not-firing-on-first-click-in-repeater-or-gridview).

Comment: I've assigned an ID to the controls that are embedded, but I don't see a difference in behavior.  None of the controls that are within the child .ascx are dynamically generated, so I'm not sure how to assign an ID other than in the <asp:whatever> tag's attribute.

Comment: If it helps, here's how I'm attaching the .ascx controls to the placeholder control:                          Control ctrlAddAdj = LoadControl("AddAdjustments.ascx");
                        ctrlAddAdj.ID = "ucAddAdj";
                        phControl.Controls.Clear();
                        phControl.Controls.Add(ctrlAddAdj);

Comment: I've also tried to attach the .ascx controls directly to a placeholder that's on a .aspx page instead of a parent .ascx page and I still see the same behavior.