# Grid view row command is firing after every second click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls

I've shopping cart in grid view. The grid is in **update panel with update mode always**. The grid view is itself in a **user control** and this user control renders in a child page (GridView --> User Control --> Child aspx page --> master page). Whenever I click on any button to modify cart the gridview row command not fires first time but when I again click on the button second time the row command fires correctly. Now I don't know  why the ***row command event*** is not firing on first click and ***it is firing only on every even click (second click)***.

**ASP:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVCart" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="CartUpdate">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_Name" HeaderText="Product Name">               
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="Button3" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Product_ID") %>'
                    CommandName="DecreseCartQty" Height="20px" ToolTip="Minus" AlternateText="+" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Product_ID") %>'
                    CommandName="IncreaseCartQty" Height="20px" ToolTip="Add" AlternateText="-" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="ABC" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemQTY")+" * "+Eval("Price")+" = "+Eval("TotalPrice") %> '></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="Button4" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Product_ID") %>' CommandName="Remove" ToolTip="Cancel"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**C#: (in user control)**

```
protected void CartUpdate(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "IncreaseCartQty")
            {

                int ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                DataTable CartDT = (DataTable)Session["cart"];

                for (int i = 0; i < CartDT.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (CartDT.Rows[i]["Product_ID"].ToString() == ProductId.ToString())
                    {
                        CartDT.Rows[i]["ItemQTY"] = Convert.ToInt32(CartDT.Rows[i]["ItemQTY"]) + 1;
                        CartDT.Rows[i]["TotalPrice"] = Convert.ToInt32(CartDT.Rows[i]["Price"]) * Convert.ToInt32(CartDT.Rows[i]["ItemQTY"]);
                        //Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
                    }
                }



            }
            if (e.CommandName == "DecreseCartQty")
            {
                int ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                DataTable CartDT = (DataTable)Session["cart"];

                for (int i = 0; i < CartDT.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (CartDT.Rows[i]["Product_ID"].ToString() == ProductId.ToString())
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(CartDT.Rows[i]["ItemQTY"]) > 1)
                        {
                            CartDT.Rows[i]["ItemQTY"] = Convert.ToInt32(CartDT.Rows[i]["ItemQTY"]) - 1;
                            CartDT.Rows[i]["TotalPrice"] = Convert.ToInt32(CartDT.Rows[i]["Price"]) * Convert.ToInt32(CartDT.Rows[i]["ItemQTY"]);
                           // Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            if (e.CommandName == "Remove")
            {
                int ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                DataTable CartDT = (DataTable)Session["cart"];

                for (int i = 0; i < CartDT.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (CartDT.Rows[i]["Product_ID"].ToString() == ProductId.ToString())
                    {
                        CartDT.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                        //Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone tell me what wrong I am doing. Your answer will be great help for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034644/itemcommand-not-firing-on-first-click-in-repeater-or-gridview) answer, I think it will solve your problem. If you have your grid view in user control this issue can arise.  I had a same issue when I had my grid view in a user control.

Answer (score 1):

It is behaving properly. You should rebind the gridview after CartUpdate so that another post back is not required.

just add these lines after

```
if (e.CommandName == "Remove")
{
    int ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());        
    DataTable CartDT = (DataTable)Session["cart"];

    for (int i = 0; i < CartDT.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (CartDT.Rows[i]["Product_ID"].ToString() == ProductId.ToString())
        {
            CartDT.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            //Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
        }
    }
}
DataTable CartDT = (DataTable)Session["cart"];
gridview1.datasource=CartDT ;
gridview1.databind();
```